# Is the windows 8 upgrade 32 bit or 64bit

Tags: windows-8

Simply like the title says is the windows 8 upgrade 32 bit or 64bit? the one that you get with the upgrade assistant?

Or is it dependent on the the system I am using to download it? 32bit system gets 32bit Windows 8, 64bit gets 64bit Windows 8?

Clarification would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Which OS are you right now on?

Comment: 32, but I would like the 64bit so I can fully use my 4gbs of ram...

Comment: My answer below has some details..

Comment: The only correct answer to this question is both, you get a single license, for either one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This website has all the details you need: [Upgrade to Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8)

> Can I upgrade from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows 8?
>   Yes, but you can't do this using Upgrade Assistant. If your PC has a 64-bit capable processor (CPU) but is currently running a 32-bit version of Windows, you can install a 64-bit version of Windows 8, but you'll need to buy Windows 8 as a DVD.
>
> You also won't be able to keep any files, settings, or apps when you
>   upgrade from a 32-bit to a 64-bit version.

I suggest you download and run the Upgrade Assistant. It would suggest what's right.

> It provides the option to buy, download, and install Windows 8. If
>   your PC is ready to go, Upgrade Assistant provides a recommendation on
>   which edition to buy, and walks you through the steps to upgrade.

Comment: So if I boot into a 64bit version of Windows (which I have windows 8 preview 64bit installed) then it will download the 64bit version?

Comment: It would suggest you what version is supported and recommended. You can then choose to download

Comment: Note that there is no official upgrade path from Windows 8 Consumer/Release Preview to Windows 8 RTM - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w8itproinstall/thread/91c5ca74-12e7-4672-b08b-76f034e23304

Comment: After you complete the Upgrade Assistant, visit [Download Windows 8 Enterprise 90-Day Evaluation](http://technet.microsoft.com/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx). It sounds stupid, but download the 64-bit evaluation-only product (expires Aug 2013), and install that just for the short length of time you need to download your ACTUAL new paid-for Windows 8 from [Windows Order Summary](mswos.com). This way, you are riding a 64-bit OS at the time you initiate the download. Or download it on any friend's 64-bit Windows system and walk the USB stick with your treasure back to your own system to install it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Upgrade to Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) page

> Can I upgrade from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows 8?
>
> Yes, but you can't do this using Upgrade Assistant. If your PC has a
>   64-bit capable processor (CPU) but is currently running a 32-bit
>   version of Windows, you can install a 64-bit version of Windows 8, but
>   you'll need to buy Windows 8 as a DVD.
>
> You also won't be able to keep any files, settings, or apps when you
>   upgrade from a 32-bit to a 64-bit version.