# Is it possible to upgrade 32-bit Windows 8 to 64-bit?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the windows 8 upgrade 32 bit or 64bit](https://superuser.com/questions/493654/is-the-windows-8-upgrade-32-bit-or-64bit)

Currently I installed Windows 8 Pro 32-bit. Is it possible to upgrade Windows 8 32-bit to 64-bit one? During installation I don't see any option to choose between 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: You will need to reinstall

Comment: I think you choose 32-bit or 64-bit through selecting which DVD you put in the caddy.

Comment: @Hennes It is not asking the same question... I don't believe it's a VTC

Answer (score 3):

No, because of the computer architecture. Those two setups are set on installation (how the CPU will treat the data, will it use 32-bit buses or 64-bit buses, addresses, etc.) and cannot be simply 'upgraded'.

You would need to reinstall the OS, as said above. In average system usage, there isn't much difference though.

Wikipedia has a good article on pros and cons - [64-bit vs 32-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Pros_and_cons) and describes the differences.

Comment: It depends on how you define the average system. These days a desktop tends to have more than 4GB of RAM, and then it does make a difference.

Comment: Indeed, that's completely true. Meant to say "for average user".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but I found on the web this link...

http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-upgrade-32bit-64bit-144649