# Can I upgrade to Windows 8 from 32 bit to 64 bit online, if I have the 64 bit disc already?

Tags: windows-8, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the windows 8 upgrade 32 bit or 64bit](https://superuser.com/questions/493654/is-the-windows-8-upgrade-32-bit-or-64bit)

I just upgraded a 32 bit Vista machine to a 64 bit Windows 8 pro with discs I got thru mail order. I have another XP sp3 machine (32 bit) that is capable of a similar upgrade. To save a little money and time, can I upgrade to 64 bits with the upgrade assistant if I use the disc I already have? meaning - Do I get a general 32/64 bit activation code from the upgrade assistant, or is it 32 bit only, or is the activation code electronically included with the upgrade, as a download image. I've heard that the upgrade assistant would only give a 32 bit upgrade. I don't know how that part of the online process happens. Thanks for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The KEY you got is generic, valid for both 32 & 64 bit.

However, when you run the online web asistant in a 32-bit machine, it will run the 32-bit installer. There is no way to override this, nor workaround. Besides most probably the 64-bit executables from CD will not run on your 32-bit operating system (vista).

To upgrade from 32 to 64, you need to run clean installation, by booting directly from your new CD of 64 bits.